# TO_CHAR invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle, date-difference

I am trying to do a date difference using sysdate. I keep getting invalid number

```
select to_char(to_date(sysdate),'MM/DD/YYYY')-to_char(pl.TEST_PLAN_LST_5YR_SUBMISSION,'MM/YYYY')
from TEST_table
```

Comment: You are converting the two dates to `char` datatype and then trying to subtract the resulting chars. You cannot subtract chars in SQL. PS I added the sql tag so users that know SQL may notice your question.

Comment: I doubt this is standard SQL though. @Kia, can you please [edit] your question and add a tag for the particular RDBMS you are using?

Comment: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with. `to_date(sysdate)` is not just useless - it's a bug in your code

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to convert dates back and forth between a date a varchar.

Just subtract those two dates:

```
select sysdate - pl.TEST_PLAN_LST_5YR_SUBMISSION
from TEST_table
```

This is assumes that `TEST_PLAN_LST_5YR_SUBMISSION` is a proper `DATE` column (and if it's not you should change that immediately - **never** store DATE values in a `VARCHAR` column).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use like this :

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2000-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') -  
   TO_DATE('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DateDiff FROM   dual
```